# Setting OptaPlanner's Vehicle Routing Solver Termination Time in Spring Boot not working

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner

I am working on a Spring Boot application where I'm using OptaPlanner for vehicle routing. I am trying to set the solver termination time in the application.properties file.

Here is my application.properties file:
`spring.optaplanner.solver.termination.spent-limit=30s`

I also tried to set the termination time by using Configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class MySolverConfig {
    public SolverConfig configureSolver() {
        SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig();
        solverConfig.getTerminationConfig().setSecondsSpentLimit(30L); 
        return solverConfig;
    }
}
```

However, it seems that the solver runs indefinitely and doesn't stop as expected. I have double-checked my configuration, but I cannot figure out what I missed. I have reviewed the OptaPlanner documentation, but I cannot identify the issue.

Can someone help me understand why the solver termination time is not being honored, and what might be missing in my configuration?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In the application.properties file, it should look like this for optaplanner (with the `spring.` prefix):

```
optaplanner.solver.termination.spent-limit=30s
```

And like this for Timefold (the continuation of OptaPlanner):

```
timefold.solver.termination.spent-limit=30s
```

For more information, [see this documentation of all properties available in Spring's application.properties](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/integration/integration#integrationWithSpringBoot).

---

That `@Configuration` approach is currently not supported. Maybe we should support it too? [Create a new issue](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues) that shows this is a spring standard way of doing that and we will look at it.

Comment: The issue got resolved after  using the xml based config
 <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>50</secondsSpentLimit> <!-- Set to the desired time limit in seconds -->
    </termination>
Thanks  Geoffrey De Smet